# Passing connection string to DLL in Azure Function

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I am trying to create Azure function out of my existing project DLLs. I have added bunch of DLLs that are using EFCore. I am trying to pass the connection string from Azure Function local.settings.json to the DLLs.

I already have Connection String defined at the local.settings.config level.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No connection string named 'PEntities' could be found in the application config file.

Startup.cs

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    var context = builder.GetContext();
    var config = context.Configuration;
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<PortalEntities>(x => x.UseSqlServer(config["PEntities"]);
}
```

local.settings.json

```
{

"IsEncrypted": false,

"Values": {

"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",

"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",

//"PEntities": "metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=Portal;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;application name=EntityFramework&quot;"

},

"ConnectionStrings": {

"PEntities": "metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=Portal;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;application name=EntityFramework&quot;"

  }

}
```

Also tried adding a partial class to override one present in DLL.

```
public partial class PortalEntities : DbContext
{
    public PortalEntities(DbContextOptions<PortalEntities> options) : base(options) 
    {
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You could share your `local.settings.json` file please ?

Comment: I have added the config @Thomas

Comment: The commented connectionstring inside the `Values` property should work (if you uncomment it).

Comment: I tried that uncommented as well. But same result